# Error when accessing member over multiple classes

Tags: c++, class, blockchain

I'm new to C++, and I'm writing a simple blockchain program as a sort of exercise. When I run the below code, I seem to get an error of sorts:

```
Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

The code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Block
{
    int data, previous_hash;
public:
    string timestamp;
    Block(string a, int b, int c)
    {
        timestamp = a;
        data = b;
        previous_hash = c;
    };
};

string getTime()
{
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm tstruct;
    char buf[40];
    tstruct = *localtime(&now);
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%X", &tstruct);
    return buf;  //Simple code to return current time
}

class BlockChain
{
public:
    Block chain[];
    BlockChain()
    {
        chain[0]=createGenesisBlock();
    }
    Block createGenesisBlock()
    {
        return Block(getTime(), 10, 0);
    }
};

int main()
{
    BlockChain myChain;
    cout << "current time is " << getTime();
    cout << myChain.chain[0].timestamp; //Is this correct?
}
```

I included a line in main() to access the string `timestamp` in my object `mychain`. I suspect this may be the problem, but i'm not sure how else I can access timestamp when its called over both `Blockchain` and `Block` classes.

Comment: [`-pedantic` is your friend](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a3fe4c49d4c77ec). You may even want to use `-pedantic-errors` until your familiarity with C++ becomes greater.

Comment: `Block chain[];` zero-sized arrays are not allowed by standard c++. If this is what you intend to do you should state the compiler and options you are using to compile your code.

Comment: Better use something like `std::vector<Block> chain;` and the `push_back()` function to add new elements to your chain.

Comment: "'m new to C++, and I'm writing a simple blockchain program as a sort of exercise." I commend your ambition. Please read no sarcasm into this comment. There is none intended. Blockchain is a hell of a way to introduce yourself to any language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, `BlockChain::chain` is an array with unknown size. But when you access `chain[0]` in `BlockChain`'s constructor, you're *assuming* that `chain` points to valid memory, which it doesn't because you never initialize it. That's why you're getting a crash due to a bad memory access. I would suggest the use of `std::vector<Block>` instead of `Block[]`, which you can resize as needed:

```
class BlockChain {
public:
    std::vector<Block> chain;
    BlockChain() {
        // initialize and append a new block to chain
        chain.emplace_back(createGenesisBlock());
    }
```

Comment: You sir are a gentleman and a scholar, switching to `vector` worked perfectly.For C++ newbies reading this, remember to `#include <vector>` too.